# Angular2 not working with basic javascript library

Tags: javascript, angular, autobahn

There seems to be an error in angular2-polyfills.js when getting a Javascript library (with its related Typescript typings) working in Angular 2 in the Browser.

It's a weird problem: I seem to be able to build and run when there is only 1 line of code from the library, but when I enter a 2nd line, it builds, but doesn't run?!?.

The library is [AutobahnJS](http://autobahn.ws/js/). It's a single .js file and the exact same library is designed to work in both the Browser and Node.
It works perfectly in both the Browser and Node as a normal (non-angular2) javascript library.
I have it working in Node using Typescript and it's related Typings (There is an [example test](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/autobahn/autobahn-tests.ts) at  the Definitely Typed github page)

I have followed the basic [Angular 2 Quickstart](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html) for Typescript and got it working no problems.

HERE is the code and output which DOES work. Note the last line in testAutobahn() is commented out:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import autobahn = require('autobahn');

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
        <h1>Project: {{_projectName}}</h1>
    `
})
export class AppComponent {

    constructor() {}

    private _projectName : string = "EXAMPLE7";

    testAutobahn() {
        var options: autobahn.IConnectionOptions =
         { url: 'wss://demo.crossbar.io/ws', realm: 'realm1' };

        //var connection = new autobahn.Connection(options);    //  <- THIS line commented out, app runs fine
    }
}
```

[image: output-working]

HERE is the code and output which does NOT work. Note the last line in testAutobahn() is left in:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import autobahn = require('autobahn');

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
        <h1>Project: {{_projectName}}</h1>
    `
})
export class AppComponent {

    constructor() {}

    private _projectName : string = "EXAMPLE7";

    testAutobahn() {
        var options: autobahn.IConnectionOptions =
         { url: 'wss://demo.crossbar.io/ws', realm: 'realm1' };

        var connection = new autobahn.Connection(options);    //  <- THIS line left in, app not run!
    }
}
```

[image: output-notworking]

The only difference is the commenting/uncommenting of that line.
The error seems to come from angular2-polyfills.js and system.src.js

I have used  'tsd' to install all the typings. They all look correct and my editor [Atom](https://atom.io/) has intellisense on the autobahn.* types just fine.

Possible issues?:

1. Using AutobahnJS v0.9.9 but the Typings seem to be for v0.9.6

   ```
   -> I can't see this being a real problem
   ```
2. When building, Typescript emits the Javascript code, but it does give an error:

> "Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable
>   '$' must be of type 'cssSelectorHelper', but here has type
>   'JQueryStatic'."

```
        -> I have resolved this error by simply commenting out the line   /* declare var $: JQueryStatic; */   in the jquery.d.ts file (I'm not using JQuery anyway)
```

Using Typescript v1.7.5, Angular 2 Beta 0 with the package.json, tsconfig.json and boot.ts files as per the [Angular 2 Quickstart](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html) for Typescript.
My end goal is to get an Angular2 Service working with AutobahnJS (but just at the baby steps at the moment).

Any help would be greatly appreciated....

Comment: There are lots of questions about this unexpected token already. They all seem related to imports. I don't know TS. I just remember seeing them answered.

Comment: does this line give you something? `console.log( autobahn.Connection );` also, comment out the `cssSelectorHelper` declaration instead of the `JQueryStatic` one, the jquery definition has lots more stuff on it, you'll find  cssSelectorHelper in two protractor files in the angular2 installation

Answer (score 0):

Well I have eventually got this working now and made *some* progress towards an AutobahnJS and Angular 2 Service. You may refer to my plunker:

```
[plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/Dgipr76Rbhgh31PH4pmM)
```

however I'm still quite stuck. The problem is I can't simply 'call' a function (where this function will then go-ahead and execute the Autobahn *session.call(...)* method) which returns a value. For example, I'm wanting to do something simple like:

```
var x = myMessageService.DoFunct1( someParameter );
```

Comment: In the mean-time, I'll take a look at [Wampy](https://github.com/KSDaemon/wampy.js) and see if I have any luck with it.